# create programmatically a UIView on mainWindow

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am creating a iphone app in which I am using Three20 open source for photo gallery. Now firstly I want to add a view in which some buttons are display and then tapping the button photo gallery show according to the button tapped category.
When I firstly open my app should shows that button screen.

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: hey try creating a new project as view based application...u will get a UIViewContoller subclass....then add a uibutton and other functionality to the view of UIViewController

Comment: but on the view based application Three20 open source doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new view like so -

```
UIView *v         = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 10)];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Add `v` as a subview to your superview. hope this helps...

Comment: By adding UIView and also adding the custom buttons on that UIView and the button selector are not working. button is not showing selected or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView *buttonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40.0f,40.0f,240.0f,400.0f)]; 

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.frame = CGRectMake(10.0f,10.0f,80.0f,50.0f); //frame is RELATIVE to PARENT view
[button setTitle:@"Button Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[buttonView addSubview:button];
[self.window addSubview:buttonView];
```